# Maven test-output folder is not updated with the build results(emailable-report is not updated after the build is successful/failure with the result)

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-grid

**Scenario:** Send an email after the build with the `emailable-report.html`.
Am able to achieve the above scenario.

But when the build is completed in jenkins, `target` folder or `test-output` folder is not updated after build. which means the jenkins workspace is not updating the `target` folder or `test-output` folder after the build. Rather the Jenkins workspace remains with the code checked out from GIT repository.

I want the jenkins workspace to be updated after the build to email the latest `emailable-report.html`.

Script for the sending the email:

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("test-output/emailable-report.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html")
```

Help me with this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

This is just because build is generating in wrong jenkins workspace due the wrong configuration that we have done earlier.

It should be something like

```
C:\Users\Ashv\.jenkins\workspace\projectname
```

and for this make sure the below configuration.

Goto Manage Jenkins>>Configure System>>Advanced

Home directory  `C:\Users\Ashv\.jenkins`

Workspace Root Directory : `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`

Build Record Root Directory: ${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds

here I am attaching my job screen for all configuration I have done.
   [you can find the link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPmHP.png)